# Lattice Gas Cellular Automata - HPP model square lattice

Tags: fluid-dynamics, simulations, lattice-model, numerical-method, cellular-automaton

In the HPP model of LGCA, a square lattice is used and there is only one collision configuration as mentioned in figure (taken from the book Lattice Gas Cellular Automata and Lattice Boltzmann models by Dieter A. Wolf-Gladrow pp. 50)

My questions are:

*1.* Why is this the **only** collision configuration? There can be others like when all four cells are filled

[image]

*2.* After the collision, the system looks like its just the **same as previous configuration** (rotation by 90 degrees); so isn't this again a collision configuration? (if it is, the collisions will continue forever and it will just oscillate between these two states)

*3.* The figure also shows the momentum vectors. In the collision configuration the momentum vectors show that the particles are moving **away** from each other instead of towards each other. So why will they collide?